# Very Simple Random Number Generator Compiling Issue

Tags: java, random, overriding, class-hierarchy

Hi i'm really new to Java and I just wanted to find out why my program wasn't compiling. Whenever I compiler the program I get an error message of:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The method nextInt(int) is undefined for the type Random

    at Random.main(Random.java:11)
```

Any input on my issue would be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.util.Random;

class Random {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Random dice = new Random();
        int number=0;

        for(int counter=1; counter<=10; counter++)
        {
            number = dice.nextInt(6);
            System.out.println(number);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: If someone want to add better explanation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.4.1) is link to Java Specification about shadowing (take a look at last code example in this paragraph about type shadowing).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are hiding the `Random` class you are importing from `java.util.Random`, by naming your class `Random`. Call it something else.

```
class RandomTest {
    ...
}
```

**Note:** Don't forget to rename the file name too with the appropriate name (`RandomTest.java` in the example above).

Answer (score 7):

You have a class called `Random` but you are also trying to use an API class also called `Random`. When you are calling `dice.nextInt(6)`, Java is calling the `nextInt` function on your class, not on the API method. To fix, change your code like so:

```
import java.util.Random;

class AnythingButRandom {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Random dice = new Random();
        int number=0;

        for(int counter=1; counter<=10; counter++)
        {
            number = dice.nextInt(6);
            System.out.println(number);
        }
    }

}
```

(then rename `Random.java` to `AnythingButRandom.java`)

Answer (score 7):

You're hiding your import, you can rename your class; or you can use the full package name

```
 java.util.Random dice = new java.util.Random(); // <-- like so
```

Answer (score 2):

When you're creating a Random dice object, it's not creating a `java.util.Random` object, it's creating an object of your own class, Random. The `nextInt` method is being called on the object of your class, and since it doesn't exist, you get the error. Name your class ANYTHING but Random, or any of your other imports for that matter. Don't forget to rename your file as well, to the same new name.

Comment: I'm just curious, how have you added anything new that isn't already provided by the other answers?

Comment: Not particularly, but I had already began typing before the rest of the answers were posted...

Comment: I was quite aware of that, that's why I posted. I had a similar problem quite a while ago with Python.

Answer (score 0):

When you are initializing a Random Object with

```
Random dice = new Random();
```

it Actually Creates an Object of your Random Class not from the java.util.Random.

If you really want your class to be called Random then use

```
java.util.Random dice = new java.util.Random();
```

But that is just plain ugly. I suggest you find a different name for your class.